# Alter data in table to add a charachter?

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I'm trying to alter a table to add the charachter `X` to every item in a certain row in my table.

I need to trunk all transaction’s in the table under a field to 40 characters, this needs to be done using a batch executed DML statement. The 40th character should be set to a `X` – to show its been shortened.

Currently I am trying to use `SUBSTR` just to trial a way of updating the lines

**Note:** On the below example is just some trial and error attempts, I created a sample table in SQL fiddle as I'm not allowed to update on main table yet

```
UPDATE test SET tester = SUBSTR(tester , 40, 1) + 'x';
```

However this returens `NULL` on all instances

I have tried

```
UPDATE test SET tester = tester + SUBSTR(tester , 40, 1) + 'x';
```

However this (when building schem in fiddler) returns

```
Schema Creation Failed: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

I have tried browsing through google and oracle data dictionary, but tbh my researching skills is pants, any ideas where I can look specifically?

I located [this](https://community.oracle.com/message/10101829) but I'm having trouble implementing

Any ideas would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this working:

```
UPDATE test SET tester = SUBSTR(tester,1,40) || 'X';
```

Comedy error using `+` instead of `||`

Can't believe it took me nearly 1 hr to figure this out! Live'n'learn I guess! :)

Answer (score 1):

The concatenation operator is `||`, not `+`. You also have your substring arguments the wrong way round; and you probably only want to apply this to values that are longer than 40 characters to start with:

```
UPDATE test
SET tester = SUBSTR(tester, 1, 39) || 'X'
WHERE LENGTH(tester) > 40;
```

This will set the 40th character to `X` only if it had to be shortened. (Although of course, if you have an original value that happened to be 40 characters long and already ended in `X` you wouldn't be able to tell whether it had been truncated.)

With starting data:

```
SELECT tester, LENGTH(tester) FROM test;

TESTER                                             LENGTH(TESTER)
-------------------------------------------------- --------------
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy 39 char value                        39 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 40 char value                       40 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza 41 char value                      41 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab 42 char value                     42 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghij 50 char value             50
```

That updates three rows and leaves you with:

```
SELECT tester, LENGTH(tester) FROM test;

TESTER                                             LENGTH(TESTER)
-------------------------------------------------- --------------
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy 39 char value                        39 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 40 char value                       40 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza 41 char valX                       40 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab 42 char vaX                       40 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghij 50X                       40
```